# Typing in recursive golang function call

Tags: json, parsing, recursion, go

I am working on adding 'array wildcards' to a Go project on Github called [jsonget](https://github.com/stvp/jsonget). Here's an example of what I mean by array wildcards:

```
 > echo "[{product:'coffee', price:2.10}, {product:'beer', price:3.80}]" | jsonget '*.price'

[2.10, 3.80]
```

The code for my branch is [here](https://github.com/tlehman/jsonget/tree/wildcards#readme)

The problem I am running into is with typing, when `GetValue` encounters a `*` character, it recurses, calling `GetValue` on the subexpression, but the type always comes back as a string.

For example, in the test file, I give it this piece of json:

```
    {
      "inventory": [
          {"name": "mountain bike", "price": 251.0},
          {"name": "red wagon", "price": 90.10},
          {"name": "kinesis advantage", "price": 300.0},
          {"name": "a ticket to Mars", "price": 1200000000.0}
      ]
    }
```

Then query out `inventory[*].price`, expecting `[251,90.1,300,1.2e+09]`, but instead getting `["251","90.1","300","1.2e+09"]`.

I would like to avoid using reflection here, but I don't see another way to do this.

Comment: Posting a snippet of code highlighting the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Your library is defined inside the `main` package - you should fix the structure of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise if i've misunderstood your question, but hopefully this helps.

I think that you're either going to have to use reflection or a type switch (http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch , which probably uses reflection behind the scenes, not sure on that).

It shouldn't be too hard to modify your existing `valueToString` function to include a type switch. Possibly rename it to `convertValue` or something more generic, and put a type switch in it. If the value is an int, return an int, else return a string.

For example:

```
func convertValue(value interface{}) (text string, i int, err error) { // Was valueToString
    if value == nil && *printNulls == false {
        return "", nil, nil
    }

    textBytes, err := json.Marshal(value)
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil, err
    }
    switch value := value.(type) {
    default:
        text = string(textBytes)
        text = quotedString.ReplaceAllString(text, "$1")
        return text, nil, nil
    case int:
        i = textBytes
        return nil, i, nil
    }
}
```

That will *hopefully* `string()` everything except the values that the type switch detects as ints, which will be returned as they are.

There's probably a cleaner way of doing it, but it would almost certainly involve a large code refactor. The major downside is that now you need to check if a value is nil before using it.

I'm not sure if there's a way to make a single function able to return one value of various types as I'm pretty sure it would play havoc with type safety. If it is possible, I can only imagine doing it by *returning* an empty interface in the function definition. Sounds messy.

EDIT: Check out Andrew Gerrand's blog post http://blog.golang.org/2011/01/json-and-go.html , especially the bit near the bottom about decoding generic data. It should help.